# How to generate the next six months?

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

I'm trying to create this template.
Expect to receive September 30, 2022 or October 1, 2022

But I get the next year the same day!

```
>>> datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 31, 9, 21, 49, 315991)
>>> rrule.rrule(freq=rrule.MONTHLY, interval=6, dtstart=datetime.today()).after(datetime.today())
datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 31, 9, 18, 3)
```

**EDIT**

I want to get a series of dates (every 6 month) and take the nearest:

```
rrule.rrule(freq=rrule.MONTHLY, interval=6, dtstart=some_date).after(datetime.today())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=dt_start, interval=183).after(datetime.today())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

six_months = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+6)
```

The output will be:

```
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2022, 3, 31)
>>> six_months
datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it takes care of issues with 28, 30, 31 days etc.

**Edit:**

relativedelta consumes these parameters:

```
years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds
```

You can also use it with any datetimeobject.

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_time_str = '18/09/19 01:55:19'
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
>>> date_time_obj + relativedelta(years=+7, months=-2, weeks=+16, days=-5, hours=+90, minutes=-100, seconds=+10, microseconds=+20)
datetime.datetime(2026, 11, 5, 18, 15, 29, 20)
```

[Documentation for relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If the parameter in after and dtstart will be different?

Comment: @ShVavilenT please check my edited answer. dtstart can be any datetimeobject, and you can tweak parameters of relativedelta to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using rrule like you have and looking at the documentation for it you need to set a number of parameters

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

# Use rrule to for 6 months from today
six_months = rrule(freq=MONTHLY, interval=6, count=3, dtstart=today)
six_months_list = list(six_months)

# Rrule to date object
for i in six_months_list:
    print(i)
```

This yields the output

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-07-01 00:00:00
2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

INTERVAL being the months you want because of the MONTHLY frequency
COUNT being the number of occurrences that show up in the list ie 3

[See documentation for rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html)

As mentioned in comments this seems to not work for using `datetime.today()`. I will need to investigate this further but it does work if using `timedelta(days=1)` to add or subtract the date.

Comment: if you run this code with today date (not the past date of 2020) you get the result:
2022-03-31 11:51:34
2023-03-31 11:51:34
2024-03-31 11:51:34

Comment: Good spot. This works perfectly if I use yesterday or tomorrow but not today, I wonder what is up with this?